# Lookup a specific series of cells by typing in a number?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I help run an RP server on discord, and we use google sheets for many of our mechanics. A new mechanic I am looking to implement is a fun little thing where they can perform an action to be given a random number from 1-20. This correlates to an item number.

The items would be listed in a sheet doc, numbered 1-20, along with a name for each item, and a description, so 3 columns total. People would take whatever number they got and reference the doc to figure out what item they receive.

My issue is this: ideally, I don't want people to see all the other items on the list, I only want them to see the one that correlates to their number. Is it possible to have a person enter a number in a cell, and have only the item information correlating with the entered number displayed? (for example, if they enter 5 in their specific cell, then you'd get '5 | item name | item description' displayed). I assume it would be some sort of lookup equation, but I'm not super skilled with coding. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As far as I understand your description, we are not talking about “search”, but about “filtering”. Have you read about the [**FILTER() function**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=uk)?

Comment: I haven't, but I can use it as a start for researching something to make it work! I think maybe I could use some sort of V-lookup too, but again, my experience is very minimal. I just really wasn't sure where to start with this.